# How can I summarize total amount

Tags: php, mysql

How can I summarize  total amount of users earning from a column "price" values?

```
$statement = "SELECT user_id, SUM(price) FROM tbl_post WHERE user_id= ".'$_SESSION['user']';
$statement = mysql_query($statement);
$user_earning= mysql_fetch_row($statement);
echo $user_earning;
```

Comment: what you got till now?

Comment: By the way, you should upgrade to Mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php. `mysql_query()` is deprecated.

Comment: Why do you have `'$_SESSION['user']'` between quotes?

Comment: There are errors and also you are doing it wrong way. You should go through the DOCs properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query should look like that:

```
select user_id,sum(price) from tbl_post where user_id=? group by user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add GROUP BY clause at select statment

```
$statement = "SELECT user_id, SUM(price)
             FROM tbl_post 
             WHERE user_id= ".'$_SESSION['user']". "
             GROUP BY user_id";
```

write above query instead of this query

```
$statement = "SELECT user_id, SUM(price) FROM tbl_post WHERE user_id= ".'$_SESSION['user']';
```

i dont know about php but by see your query you want to sum of all price of a perticular user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have error in your query :

```
$statement = "SELECT user_id, SUM(price) FROM tbl_post WHERE user_id= '".$_SESSION['user']."' ";
$statement = mysql_query($statement); 
$user_earning= mysql_fetch_row($statement); 
echo $user_earning[1];// echo $user_earning['price'];
```